# Do small helicopters like the R44 require an FAA type rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter, pilot-certification, robinson-r44

From what I read in [14 CFR 61.31](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_131) it never mentions type rating requirements for rotorcraft or helicopters. I Googled online but most of the results showed up for Australia, Canada and the UK.

I am starting to believe that the US does not require a pilot to have a type rating for a Robinson [R22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R22) or [R44](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R44) helicopter.

Am I correct that unless the FAA has made a type certificate for that helicopter it does not require a type rating? Would it just require a checkout from wherever you are going to rent?

Comment: Keep in mind that many pilots will spend their very first rotorcraft hours in a R22...

Comment: From Wikipedia's article on the R22: "Due to the issues relating to a low inertia rotor-system and a teetering main rotor, operation by any pilot in the United States of the Robinson R22 or Robinson R44 requires a special endorsement by a certified flight instructor."

Comment: Pls correct me i am confused. Type certificate is for aircraft to operate legally. Type rating is for airman to legally operate the aircraft that required one. See [type certificate of R22](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/3a27e3925f44c55486257bc9005dca07/$FILE/H10WE_Rev_15.pdf)

Comment: @vasin1987 You are correct. A type certificate is required for an aircraft type to be legally operated regardless of whether its pilots are required to have a type rating to operate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SFAR 73](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#ap14.2.61.1) is *Robinson R-22/R-44 Special Training and Experience Requirements* and lists the specific training requirements for that model. Here's one relevant piece:

> (1) No person may act as pilot in command of a Robinson model R-22
>   unless that person:
>
> (i) Has had at least 200 flight hours in helicopters, at least 50
>   flight hours of which were in the Robinson R-22; or
>
> (ii) Has had at least 10 hours dual instruction in the Robinson R-22
>   and has received an endorsement from a certified flight instructor
>   authorized under paragraph (b)(5) of this section that the individual
>   has been given the training required by this paragraph and is
>   proficient to act as pilot in command of an R-22. Beginning 12
>   calendar months after the date of the endorsement, the individual may
>   not act as pilot in command unless the individual has completed a
>   flight review in an R-22 within the preceding 12 calendar months and
>   obtained an endorsement for that flight review. The dual instruction
>   must include at least the following abnormal and emergency procedures
>   flight training: [...]

[SFAR 108](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#ap14.2.91.8) has similar requirements for operating the [Mitsubishi MU-2B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_MU-2).

Finally, note that the *type certificate* is for the aircraft, and has nothing to do with whether an individual pilot is qualified to fly it or not.

Comment: When I first read this, I missed the 'or' and the end of `(1)(i)` and I was really confused as to how you were supposed to get 50 hours in an R-22 if only 10 of it was dual instruction and you weren't allowed to act as PIC. - haha

Comment: It's important to note that SFAR73 is modeled after an aircraft type rating, and behaves as such.

Comment: Thanks, In summary 10 hours of dual to get a endorsement that last 12 months. And if you don't have 50 hours after 12 months you need to do a flight review before continuing to fly on it.

Answer (score 6):

The FAA does indeed require model-specific type ratings for many aircraft (a list of aircraft which the FAA recognizes type ratings for is [here](http://registry.faa.gov/TypeRatings/)). [FAR 61.31](http://www.risingup.com/fars/info/part61-31-FAR.shtml) says that type ratings are required for

> (1) Large aircraft (except lighter-than-air).
>
> (2) Turbojet-powered airplanes.
>
> (3) Other aircraft specified by the Administrator through aircraft
>   type certificate procedures.

In this context, according to [Advisory Circular 61-89E](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/22886), "large" means it has a gross weight of 12,500 lbs or greater. In addition, based on (2) above, you need a type rating in the US to fly any jet, even small, single-engine jets or those designed specifically for single-pilot operation.

Comment: Purely for argument's sake, would a propfan-powered aircraft count as a "turbojet" for the purposes of FAR 61.31?  What about a turboprop?